# scala iterate on subset of list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraylist, iteration

I am from a python world, doing some scala work, somebody help me on this. I have a start and end date, I created a date list with that like this,

```
def dateRange(from: DateTime, to: DateTime, step: Period) : Iterator[DateTime] = {
  Iterator.iterate(from)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(to))
}

val from = new DateTime().withYear(2012).withMonthOfYear(1).withDayOfMonth(1)
val to = new DateTime().withYear(2018).withMonthOfYear(2).withDayOfMonth(1)
val step = new Period().withDays(1)

// Getting the iterative date lists
val range = dateRange(from, to, step)
val dateList = range.toList

val dates = dateList.map { p => p.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") }
```

However, now I need to iterate on this, however take only a subset of list elements every iteration.

Lets say, I have a list like this:

```
['2014-01-01','2014-01-02','2014-01-03','2014-01-04','2014-01-05','2014-01-06', ...]
```

For every iteration, I need to send 3 dates. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: grouped on List:

```
list.grouped(3).toList
```

This will give you List[List[T]]

For example lets consider input to be:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

After applying list.grouped(3).toList, output will be:

```
List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6), List(7,8))
```

Iterate over the list. This will do the needful

Comment: Thanks. But how can I access each element in the inside list and assign it to a variable. ? I will have 3 separate variables inside the loop to hold these values.

Comment: If you'll iterate over the outer list, outerList.map(x => 
val innerList = x). Here innerList will be List(1,2,3) You can further iterate over the inner list to access one element at a time of the inner list.

Comment: I need to assign 3 values of the inner list in to 3 different variables and call my function.

Comment: iterate over the inner list and store each value in  a different variable, as done with the outer list(i.e val innerlist = x )

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand this part, can you add this example with your answer. I understand until iterating over innerlist, but for each innerlist, I don’t want to iterate within them. I want to assign the innerlist elements in to separate variables. I am trying to understand how I can access the elements here like x[1] in Languages like r.

Comment: Adhoc way to do it is like -> val (x,y,z) = (List(0),List(1),List(2)), this will assign inner list values to x,y, and z

Comment: Thank. That’s what I wanted.

Comment: just to give a further input on it, this adhoc way might fail as list length is not decided before runtime and assigning to variables needs to be known before it.

Comment: Yes, I am now thinking of dynamic way to create these variables.